# Deploying default Wifi settings and Passwords

Tags: macos, airport, preferences, keychain, mdm

I am building a default 10.8 image for our corporate Mac users.  We have a local Wifi network which should be set up by default on this image.  I have used PackageMaker to set up all the other deployed software and settings, and would *like* to keep it that way.  I am using InstaDMG to build the image (another reason to prefer the modular packaging method I have in place).

I have tried deploying a .keychain file to `/Library/Keychains/`, but the AP is not picked up;      I am also aware of `/Library/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` but after deploying this, the system still does not result in the expected behavior.

How can I deploy system-wide Wifi settings to a unbooted images using packages?

Comment: You might want to specify the OS you are building, as there are major changes between 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8 as to how network configurations can be imported and exported.

Comment: OS Version Added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe PackageMaker includes some first-run scripts, does it not? The easiest way is probably to make use of the [networksetup](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) command line tool in a script set to run on the first launch of an image.

To add a WPA network:

```
networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex AirPort mynetworkSSID 0 WPA superSecretPassword
```

The encryption type can be one of:

- `OPEN` — open hotspot, no passphrase necessary of course.
- `WPA`
- `WPAE` (WPA Enterprise)
- `WPA2`
- `WPA2E` (WPA2 Enterprise)
- `WEP`
- `8021XWEP` (802.1X WEP)